# If a metric space X is compact (sequentially compact) than is it complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

If a metric space $(X,d) $ is compact than it is complete. Am I right? If yes, than when will a complete metric space be compact?

Comment: A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded

Comment: @Surb can you explain a bit more as I am failed to get you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Bbb R$ is complete but not compact

Comment: This is the converse.